# Intersections of two cones with parallel axes

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, 3d

In mathpages, ["On the Ellipse"](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath631/kmath631.htm), the author starts, as usual, by considering an intersection of a plane and a cone. But, in order to derive further properties of the ellipse, he immediately states after that

> By symmetry, the locus of intersection between the cone and the plane is also the locus of intersection of two right cones with parallel axes offset from each other, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

Why should this be the case, a-priori?
Is there any reason to think, without any derivations\algebra, that it should be symmetric about this axis? Or vice versa, that the intersections of two right cones with parallel axes should be planar - without any proof or calculations?

The author doesn't regard this point anywhere in this page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Equivalently, why is the intersection of these two cones contained within a plane?

Comment: If the apex is at the origin the equation of a right circular cone is $$\frac1{\sqrt2}=\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{n_x x+ n_y y+n_z z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},$$ where $[n_x, n_y, n_z]$ is the unit normal vector along the axis. This means that if you have two translated to different apexes the intersection will be contained in a plane, just by the fact that the quadratic terms cancel.

Comment: Those are oblique cones, not right cones, since the altitudes are not perpendicular to the elliptical base.

Answer (score 1):

Look from the front so the picture is in 2D.

Imagine translating each of the two edges of down-cone, so that they connect with the edge's intersection with the vertical side of the cylinder. This way you constructed a parallelogram. Therefore, you see the angle of the up-cone and the down-cone (in 3D, solid angle) must be equal - that they are really from the same cone. Now the symmetry about the axis is simple from trigonometry.
[image]

Comment: Succinct way: notice the parallelogram

Comment: Do you mind explaining a bit further about the symmetry about the axis?

Comment: From the diagram, you can see the two axis are the same distance from the side (or the center) of the cylinder. And as the axis of the 2 cones are parallel, you could imagine flipping the picture up to down, and then right to left, and you get the exact same picture.

Comment: Why should the upper (constructed) cone should be a  right cone, and not some other wonky symmetric shape?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.

Suppose the plane is passing through the origin and cutting the upper right cone with apex $(0,0,T)$ at an ellipse $E$. Reflect the cone about $xy$-plane obtaining a lower cone. Then translate the lower cone so that it passes through $E$.